# Johnny-Five problems with Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, arduino, johnny-five, firmata

I'm having troubles trying to use Johnny-Five with my Arduino Mega. The main problem is that it requires Node.js and I'm following the really easy instructions from [this link](http://johnny-five.io/examples/board-with-port/), but typing `node blink.js` in the terminal it throw me an error [like that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43940412/node-js-error-cannot-find-module).

I searched for that problem and [someone says](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/7032) Node.js needs Xcode (that seems to work as a C++ compiler) to work properly. I use a MacBook Air and I don't want a 5+ GB app if not needed, so I want to know if my problem is that I haven't installed that app or it's something else.

Comment: Not a coding problem. This question would be more suited for https://arduino.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because you didn't install the module.
I don't have time to read the full instruction, but I think you use some kind of module and you didn't installed it.

You need to run the command inside your project directory `npm install ModuleName`

If you didn't install node, you just need to install it with the mac installer.

Answer (score 0):

You can install the XCode CLI tools only which includes the gcc compiler:

```
xcode-select --install
```

That should be everything that you need, and is a much smaller package (Not sure of the actual size but I believe it is well under 1gb).